# Determine if a variable is an empty jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Setup:

```
<div>
  <div class="application-section active"></div>
  <div class="application-section"></div>      
</div>
```

I am setting a the following variables

```
var $activeSection = $("div.application-section.active"); 
var $targetSection = $activeSection.prev("div.application-section");
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) states that if no previous sibiling is found, it will return a blank jquery object.   I want to do additional stuff if the variable is a blank jQuery object, but how do you check to see if it is a blank jQuery object? I have tried the following, but I always get false as a result.

```
alert($.isEmptyObject($targetSection));
```

Comment: To be fair, the duplicate question would have been hard to find because it is written confusingly. A jQuery selector can't "return null".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$targetSection.length` will be zero if no matching selector is found.